# Ubuntu 14 stuck at loading screen

Tags: boot

I was trying to install the crossover package on my laptop when the following happened:

1. Icons started getting removed from the sidebar (or launcher?)
2. The package manager was unresponsive for >5 minutes when I tried to stop the installation
3. I tried to shutdown and at this point everything else was also unresponsive
4. I shut it down with a long press of the power button
5. I start it again and it's stuck in the start up screen (purple background + 5 dots)

`apt-get upgrade` results in this:

[image] 
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

`fsck`:

[image]

There were some other questions which were solved by fixing LightDM; however that's correct in my laptop.

This is the output on pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

[image: kernel output]

There was a thread which suggested `aptitude install lightdm` but when I do that I'm told that all the packages mentioned above (in `apt-get upgrade`) will be removed and ~500 MB will be freed. So I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Comment: more details needed like dmesg and syslog along with your h/w configuration

Comment: My laptop is an inspiron 3521; afaik it has an Intel graphics card and not nvidia! $ nvidia detector -> none

Comment: You probably broke a few packages when you shut down your computer in the middle of an upgrade. Please [edit] your question to include (a link to) the content of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`. Also, please use text instead of images to reproduce text content (see [How can I run a command and copy its output?](/q/335770/175814) and [How can I easily share the output of a command or a text file with others?](/q/152371/175814)). It is much more accessible and searchable.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Thanks for the edit! I wrote the question from my phone when I was locked out of my laptop; hence the crappy formatting! I had to resort to uploading images because I wasn't able to login but was stuck with the terminal that we get on doing `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1`.  There's no copy-paste there!

Comment: The questions linked in my previous comment contain many approaches to purely command-line based solutions which work in any virtual terminal. You only need a working internet connection (or a writeable external storage medium and a seconds computer – but this way is more complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random thought made me try `unity -v` which told me that unity wasn't installed.

`$ sudo apt-get install unity` and I got to the login screen. Here I couldn't get in despite entering the correct password.

By following the steps given [here](http://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/) I entered `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and managed to login.

A few programs that were previously installed are now missing but I managed to login successfully without losing any files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
dconf reset -f /etc/compiz 
unity --replace --reset-icon &disown
```

and it might work fine this way

Comment: I've already solved the issue using `sudo apt-get install unity` so there's no way for me to test your solution but it looks similar, so please leave it here! Thanks!